# Running and testing a property expressing a relationship between TAKE and APPEND

Tags: testing, lisp, proof, acl2

Basically, I need to write a what the title says, the only relationship I have been able to think of is if I take some number of elements from a list with `TAKE` and then take the not-as-important other half with `CDR` and then `APPEND` the two that I took to prove that it's the same as the original list.
(After long painful hours of building it), the proof seems to be fine (It compiles just fine), but for some reason it fails when run.
I am using Proofpad with Dracula, in case you need the information.

Here is the code:

```
(include-book "doublecheck" :dir :teachpacks)

(defproperty take-append-relationship-test ;not sure why this fails.
   (xs :value (random-integer-list))
   (iff (consp xs)
        (let* ((x1 (take 1 xs))
               (xs2 (cdr xs)))
            (equal (append x1 xs2)
                   xs))))
```

Here is the error log I get.

```
By the simple :definition TAKE we reduce the conjecture to

Goal'
(COND ((CONSP XS)
       (LET ((X1 (FIRST-N-AC 1 XS NIL)))
            (EQUAL (APPEND X1 (CDR XS)) XS)))
      ((LET ((X1 (FIRST-N-AC 1 XS NIL)))
            (EQUAL (APPEND X1 (CDR XS)) XS))
       NIL)
      (T T)).

This simplifies, using the :definition FIRST-N-AC, the :executable-
counterparts of BINARY-+, BINARY-APPEND, CONS, FIRST-N-AC and ZP, primitive
type reasoning and the :rewrite rules DEFAULT-CAR and DEFAULT-CDR,
to

Goal''
(IMPLIES (CONSP XS)
         (EQUAL (APPEND (FIRST-N-AC 1 XS NIL) (CDR XS))
                XS)).

The destructor terms (CAR XS) and (CDR XS) can be eliminated by using
CAR-CDR-ELIM to replace XS by (CONS XS1 XS2), (CAR XS) by XS1 and (CDR XS)
by XS2.  This produces the following goal.

Goal'''
(IMPLIES (CONSP (CONS XS1 XS2))
         (EQUAL (APPEND (FIRST-N-AC 1 (CONS XS1 XS2) NIL)
                        XS2)
                (CONS XS1 XS2))).

This simplifies, using primitive type reasoning, to

Goal'4'
(EQUAL (APPEND (FIRST-N-AC 1 (CONS XS1 XS2) NIL)
               XS2)
       (CONS XS1 XS2)).

Normally we would attempt to prove Goal'4' by induction.  However,
we prefer in this instance to focus on the original input conjecture
rather than this simplified special case.  We therefore abandon our
previous work on this conjecture and reassign the name *1 to the original
conjecture.  (See :DOC otf-flg.)

No induction schemes are suggested by *1.  Consequently, the proof
attempt has failed.

Summary
Form:  ( DEFTHM TAKE-APPEND-RELATIONSHIP-TEST ...)
Rules: ((:DEFINITION FIRST-N-AC)
        (:DEFINITION IFF)
        (:DEFINITION TAKE)
        (:ELIM CAR-CDR-ELIM)
        (:EXECUTABLE-COUNTERPART BINARY-+)
        (:EXECUTABLE-COUNTERPART BINARY-APPEND)
        (:EXECUTABLE-COUNTERPART CONS)
        (:EXECUTABLE-COUNTERPART FIRST-N-AC)
        (:EXECUTABLE-COUNTERPART ZP)
        (:FAKE-RUNE-FOR-TYPE-SET NIL)
        (:REWRITE DEFAULT-CAR)
        (:REWRITE DEFAULT-CDR))
Time:  0.00 seconds (prove: 0.00, print: 0.00, other: 0.00)
Prover steps counted:  328

---
The key checkpoint goal, below, may help you to debug this failure.
See :DOC failure and see :DOC set-checkpoint-summary-limit.
---

*** Key checkpoint before reverting to proof by induction: ***

Goal''
(IMPLIES (CONSP XS)
         (EQUAL (APPEND (FIRST-N-AC 1 XS NIL) (CDR XS))
                XS))

ACL2 Error in ( DEFTHM TAKE-APPEND-RELATIONSHIP-TEST ...):  See :DOC
failure.

******** FAILED ********
```

Could someone at least point me in the right direction?
I have read the error log and what I get is that there is some sort of redundancy.
I am not sure how to fix this at all.

---

If I do that (so like `'(1 2 3 4)` instead of `(random-integer-list)`), it throws an error:

```
ACL2 Error in TOP-LEVEL:  One value, '(1 2 3 4 5), is being returned
where 2 values were expected.  Note:  This error occurred in the context
(MV-LET (XS STATE)
        '(1 2 3 4 5)
        (IF T
            (MV-LET (STATE RESULT ASSIGNMENTS)
                    (EXPAND-VARS NIL (IFF # #))
                    (MV STATE RESULT (CONS # ASSIGNMENTS)))
            (MV STATE 'WHERE-NOT-MATCHED NIL))).
(See :DOC set-iprint to be able to see elided values in this message.)
```

---

My setup:

1. Install Racket
2. Open it and run the following code:

   (pound)lang racket 
   (require (planet cce/dracula:8:23/lang/dracula))
3. Restart Dr Racket. Click the "Choose Language" at the bottom of the window and choose ACL2 under Dracula.
4. From the Dracula menu, choose "Change ACL2 Executable Path..." and choose "run_acl2" (or "run_acl2.exe") which is located in the installation folder of proofpad (i.e. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Proof Pad", if you have a 64 bits PC)
5. [download PSP++ and run it](http://www.cs.ou.edu/~rlpage/SEtools/Tools/PSP++readme.html). Make sure to unzip it in the Proofpad installation directory, otherwise it will tell you it didn't find the things it needed.

Comment: I haven't used the proof system that you're working with, but I wonder if the theorem you're trying to prove actually holds.  Not having worked with ACL, I don't know what the definition of `TAKE` is, and it's not included here.  What happens when `xs` is the empty list (which I'd hope is trivially a list of integers)?  If `(take 1 '())` is `()`, and `(cdr '())` is `'()`, then `(append (take 1 '()) (cdr '()))` is `'()`, but `(consp '())` is false.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the error log suggests redundancy to you?  I note, "We therefore abandon our previous work on this conjecture and reassign the name *1 to the original conjecture.  (See :DOC otf-flg.)  No induction schemes are suggested by *1.  Consequently, the proof attempt has failed."  It sounds like you're getting a form where the system is trying to apply an induction scheme, but doesn't find any applicable ones.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes sorry, I got myself confused with a previous error I had got. Yes I understood that about not being able to apply induction, however I'm not sure how to solve it.
Here is the definition of [`TAKE`](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/v6-2/TAKE.html)
So  (take 1 '()) actually is (nil)

Comment: I got that file from PSP++ I think. I think [these instructions](http://www.cs.ou.edu/~rlpage/SEtools/Tools/PSP++readme.html) would help.

Comment: I found the [DoubleCheck](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/cce/acl2/doublecheck.html) (a Dracula teachpack for randomized testing), but that seems for a Scheme environment rather than an ACL2 environment built on a Common Lisp, so I'm not sure how to proceed.  On a different route, what happens if you try running this proof on a fixed input rather than a `(random-integer-list)`?

Comment: *The error log looks confusing here, I'll put it up in the question

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about your setup?  This probably wouldn't be all that necessary for more commonly used languages and environments, but from what I can tell, Dracula is a teachpack for DrRacket.  I think I've got the Dracula package installed (by, according to [the instructions](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=dracula.plt&owner=cce) evaluating `(require (planet cce/dracula:8:23/lang/dracula))`, but in evaluating your code with the require (i.e., `(require …) (include-book …) (defproperty …)`) I get an…

Comment: …error: `rename-below: defined outside of begin-below in: here`.  Can you describe your setup and what one would need to do to be able to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Setup explained above.

Comment: I've managed to get DrRacket up and running with the Dracula teachpack, and pointed to an installation of ACL2 (I'm on Ubuntu though, so the Proofpad stuff doesn't apply, I guess.)  I tried following the instructions on the PSP++ installation (opening main.lisp in DrRacket in ACL2 mode), but had no luck there. Others reading this may find the [Dracula installation instructions](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/cce/acl2/) useful.  You may find that you'll have better luck in getting an answer to this if you write…

Comment: …to the [ACL2 mailing lists](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/v6-2/installation/misc.html#Addresses).  If you do have any luck there, I'd encourage you to report the results back here (as an answer, which you can then accept!) afterward.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about these mailing lists.